# Spring AnnotationConfigApplicationContext StartupStep spring.context.annotated-bean-reader.create

Tags: java, spring

In AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
line 67

```
public AnnotationConfigApplicationContext() {
    StartupStep createAnnotatedBeanDefReader = this.getApplicationStartup().start("spring.context.annotated-bean-reader.create");
    this.reader = new AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader(this);
    createAnnotatedBeanDefReader.end();
    this.scanner = new ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(this);
}
```

this `StartupStep` is `DefaultApplicationStartup`

[image]

`start("spring.context.annotated-bean-reader.create")` this name is useless.

So why is it passed in this method?

Comment: What makes you think that name is useless. The default implementation is a noop implementation when you decide to use the `FlightRecorderStartupStep` to trigger events to the Java Flight Recorder the name isn't useless.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but in my opinion

Comment: thank you for your answer. but in my opinion. in this case
private ApplicationStartup applicationStartup = ApplicationStartup.DEFAULT; ApplicationStartup DEFAULT = new DefaultApplicationStartup();  Isn't this useless？

Comment: No it isn't. The fact that it isn't used by 1 implementation means it isn't useful for other implementations. How should the `start` method know which implementation it is and if the passed in parameter is used or not that is for the actual implementation to know.

Comment: emmm…… I mean mybe in this case . I can write like this : ` StartupStep createAnnotatedBeanDefReader = this.getApplicationStartup().start("");`  Are they the same ?  Or is his implementation at runtime `FlightRecorderStartupStep`

Comment: No you cannot write that as the user of that code doesn't know which implementation is being used.